# compiler cannot compile inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose i have a header which contain these two classes

```
class A:public class B{
 // code
};
class B 
{
protected:
A a_object;
};
```

when the compiler compiles this include file,when it comes to Class A ,it sees class A inherits from B but it doesn't reach to Class B definition.So it gives an error. and if i reverse the order of both classes,it gives error due to a_object as it doesn't see Class A definition.

So how to solve this problem? and assume that i restricted to this include file to have class A and B definitions.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this kind of recursive dependencies.

Comment: Think about it. The size of an `A` will include the size of the `a_object` it inherits from `B`, so `sizeof(A)` is infinity. Obviously, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your problem:

```
class X {
    X x;
};
```

A class cannot embed an object of its own type.

Specifically, your class `B` embeds an object of type `A`, which by inheritance is also of type `B`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to have a hierarchy like that you can do something like the following.

```
class A;

class B 
{
protected:
  A* a_object;
};

class A: public B {
  // code
};
```